# React native stuck at "Loading Dependency Graph, done"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, windows-10

I am using react native in windows 10. Whenever I run `npm start`, it freezes after sometime.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ │
│ Running Metro Bundler on port 8081. │
│ │
│ Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to │
│ close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer. │
│ │
│ https://github.com/facebook/react-native │
│ │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   G:\projects\my-app

Loading dependency graph, done.

To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"
```

And freezes after it. Why it is so?

Comment: Do you use `expo`?

Comment: Yes but is showing the error: `something went wrong` 

`could not load exp://192.168.1.36:19000 network not response timed out`